# What's the difference between 顿 and 道 as a measure word for meals?

Tags: measure-word

What's the difference between 顿 and 道 as a measure word for meals? What each measure word stresses?

1. 吃了一顿饭
2. 吃了一道饭

Looks like 顿 used to mean 点头 diǎntóu or 鞠躬 jūgōng. If it's so, then presenting "a dish" with a 鞠躬 makes some sence and can explain why 顿 started to be used as a measure word for this type of thing.

But 道 as far as I know is used for crooked thinks like roads and lightnings. Can 道 be used as "a round" like in boxing. "Next round of meals"...

Comment: see dictionary, e.g.bkrs：   **顿**   classifier for meals, beatings, scoldings etc: 挨了一顿骂 get a scolding
说了他一顿 give him a dressing-down
一天三顿饭 three meals a day 
  **道**  classifier for long thin things (rivers, cracks etc), barriers (walls, doors etc), questions (in an exam etc), commands, courses in a meal, steps in a process
(old) administrative division (similar to province in Tang times)

Comment: I know what dictionary says. But simply by looking at the dictionary datum I can't see why there are 2 measure words for MEALS. 
Is there etymological connection between 顿 as a meal and 顿 as a conflict.

Comment: 顿 - looks like a bud + a head = maybe it's a swelling on the forehead after deep bow? Maybe it's how 顿 got it "measure word for conflict meaning"?

Comment: I am not quite sure the etymology of 顿 as a meal. My guess will be that 顿 can mean 'Pause' and 'sudden', so meals are separated with Pauses.

Comment: I thought meals should be separated with deep bows... :) You know, like those meals in the Emperor Palace.

Comment: reply to #2: dictionary: measure word/CL for meal 顿, CL for course in a meal 道, answers say the same, people knowing what (this) dictionary says, know that that there are not 2 measure words for meals, only one for meal and another one for course in a meal. If there is a problem telling the difference between "meal" and "course in a meal" answers were accepted w/o explaining the difference.

Answer (score 6):

一頓饭 is one meal whereas 一道菜 is one course or one dish.

這頓豐富的晚餐共有十二道菜。

This sumptuous dinner is made up of twelve courses.

Comment: So sometimes one 頓 consists of 12 courses 道?

Comment: @coobit There isn't any relationship like that. One 顿 can consists of any number of courses.

Comment: Yes, a very formal banquet dinner (wedding, birthday ... etc.) typically consists of 12 courses and way too much food, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

一道饭 is a wrong expression. It should be 一道菜.

Both 顿 and 道 can be measure words. For example,

顿: 一顿饭，打一顿，揍一顿...

道：一道菜，一道题目，一道伤疤...